# unsupported object format while deploying serverless template

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm encountering a problem while trying to import values from AWS CloudFormation Outputs into my Lambda functions within the Serverless Framework. My aim is to use the default VPC network in my Lambda function by exporting default subnet IDs and importing them into the Lambda configuration.

In my CloudFormation template, I've set up Parameters for default subnet IDs and exported these values as Outputs. Here's a snippet of what I've done:

```
Parameters:
  DefaultPrivateSubnetIds:
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-******

  DefaultPrivateSubnetIds2:
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-******

Output:
  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: "Value of the first private subnet"
    Value: !Ref DefaultPrivateSubnetIds
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}-DefaultPrivateSubnetId

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Description: "Value of the second private subnet"
    Value: !Ref DefaultPrivateSubnetIds2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}-DefaultPrivateSubnetId2
```

However, when attempting to import these values into my Lambda function's VPC configuration in the Serverless YAML file, I encounter errors:

```
getDischarge:
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - ${env:DEFAULT_SG_RDS,'sg-40f6450e'} 

    subnetIds:
      - ${env:SUBNET_A, Fn::ImportValue: ${self:provider.stage}-PrivateSubnet1}
      - ${env:SUBNET_B, Fn::ImportValue: ${self:provider.stage}-PrivateSubnet2}
```

The errors reported in the CloudFormation console are:

```
module.<>_backend.null_resource.this (local-exec):   at 'functions.getDischarge.vpc.securityGroupIds.0': unsupported object format
module.<>_backend.null_resource.this (local-exec):   at 'functions.getDischarge.vpc.subnetIds.0': unsupported object format
```

For now I fixed it directly by providing hard-coded values but it doesn't look professional in code, so I need a way to provide those values in correct format.

I suspect the issue might be related to the format of the exported values or how I'm referencing them in the Serverless configuration. From what I've researched, CloudFormation exports values as strings by default. However, I'm unsure if my Serverless YAML file references these values correctly.

How can I correctly import these exported values into my Lambda function's VPC configuration within the Serverless Framework? Should the exported values be formatted differently for proper referencing in the Serverless configuration?

Any guidance or corrections to my approach would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to use outputs of a different stack as a part of config is to use `cf` variable source as documented here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-cloudformation-outputs

The errors you're seeing are caused by the fact that Serverless Framework seems to not be able to resolve the env variables for subnetId. If you run `sls print`, you will see that the values resolved for `subnetIds` are not the ones that you'll expect them to be. In general, defaulting variable resolution to an object might be a bit tricky, which is why I would recommend using `cf` variable source directly that seems to cover your case pretty nicely.